# How to run multiple browsers in a single Selenium Node machine

Tags: browser, selenium, grid, command

How do I run multiple browsers in a single Selenium Node machine. What is command for this in command prompt. Can any body help me on this.

Answer (score 3):

By default, the nodes can run..

#### RC

- 5 Firefox browsers
- 5 Chrome browsers
- 1 IE browser

#### WebDriver

- 5 Firefox browsers
- 5 Chrome browsers
- 1 IE browser

So technically, a default node can run 22 browsers at a time.  All you need to do, is if you have, say, 2 nodes, when you fire a test at the grid, it allocates 1 test per open machine **FIRST** then it stacks browsers.  Once you run 3 tests, it then opens that third session against the next available browser.

If You'd like to customize this, just create a `config.json` file, and specify the `maxSessions`

```
{
  "capabilities":
      [
        {
          "browserName": "*chrome",
          "maxInstances": 2,
          "seleniumProtocol": "Selenium"
        }
      ],
  "configuration":
  {
    "proxy": "org.openqa.grid.selenium.proxy.DefaultRemoteProxy",
    "maxSession": 10,
    "port": 5555,
    "register": true,
    "registerCycle": 5000,
    "hubPort": 4444
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

nothing special about this:
just concat the browsers in the start script:

```
java \
  -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.33.0.jar \
  -role node \
  -browser browserName=**firefox**,version=3.6,maxInstances=5,platform=WINDOWS \
  -browser browserName=**chrome**,maxInstances=5,platform=WINDOWS \
  -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=f:\chromedriver.exe
```

maybe this can be helpful too if you wish to use Grid without the hard work of configuring
each node as u grow:
[efficient we ui testing lab](http://www.ravellosystems.com/blog/build-effective-web-ui-testing-lab/)

[disclosure : i work at Ravello]

Answer (score 2):

Use follwing command while registering node on hub

```
java - Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=C:\chromedriver.exe -Dwebdriver.ie.driver=C:\internetdriver\IEDriverServer.exe -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.46.0.jar -role webdriver -hub http://192.168.1.10:4444/grid/register -port 7777 -browser browserName=chrome,maxInstances=3, -browser browserName=firefox,maxInstances=3, -browser browserName=iexplore,maxInstances=3 –maxSession 3
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Selenium itself supports different browsers. (In other answers are given examples how to setup amount of sessions per browser)
2. you need to have different Browser-drivers installed (by default there would be FF at least or maybe + chrome)
3. in your client part you need to specify which browser to run test on
   for two browsers it will be two test runs (could be done simultaneously )